# Why does this dateFormatter log (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to convert a nsstring into date with the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:quota.datetime];
```

The string quota.datetime looks like this:

```
2016-02-17 22:00:00
```

However, when I NSLog date, I get (null). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yyyy` - 4-digit year.
`mm` - 2-digit minute. Hmmm. You are using that for both the month and minutes. That can't be right. 2-digit month is `MM`.
`dd` - 2-digit day.
`hh` - 2-digit 12-hour. Hmmm. Your date string is in 24-hour time. The spec says that requires `HH`.
`ss` - 2-digit second.

So based on looking at the documentation and the date string you wish to parse, you need the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: So I've changed month to MM. I'm still getting null. Does it make a difference if the dateFormatter is in a block?

Comment: Did you also change the `hh` to `HH` as I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this . This will help you.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;

if (!formatter){
     formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];//2015-09-04 09:34:00
 }

 NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2015-09-04 09:34:00"];
```

Below is commonly used specifiers used in the date format string :

```
y = year
Q = quarter
M = month
w = week of year
W = week of month
d = day of the month
D = day of year
E = day of week
a = period (AM or PM)
h = hour (1-12)
H = hour (0-23)
m = minute
s = second
```

Follow this link to know more about [DateForamtter and Date Format](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates).